# Two AJAX form submissions in a single JS file, only one is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

In the HTML, the forms look identical, just the form ID is changed. I use this JS file to submit the forms using AJAX:

```
$("#change-password").submit(function(e) {
    var url = "http://domain/actions"; 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#change-password").serialize(), 
        success: function(data) {
            $("div.change-password-response").html(data);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); 
});

$("#change-email").submit(function(e) {
    var url = "http://domain/actions"; 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#change-email").serialize(), 
        success: function(data) {
            $("div.change-email-response").html(data);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

HTML Part

```
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 add_bottom_30">
                    <h4>Schimbare parola</h4>
                    <form id="change-password" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Parola veche</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="old_password" id="old_password" type="password" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Parola noua</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="new_password" id="new_password" type="password" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Confirma parola noua</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="confirm_new_password" id="confirm_new_password" type="password" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="change-password">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn_1 green">Actualizeaza parola</button>
                    <div class="change-password-response form-response"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 add_bottom_30">
                    <h4>Schimbare adresa email</h4>
                    <form id="change-email" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email vechi</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="old_email" id="old_email" type="text" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email nou</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="new_email" id="new_email" type="text" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Confirma email nou</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="confirm_new_email" id="confirm_new_email" type="password" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="change-email">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn_1 green">Actualizeaza Email</button>
                    <div class="change-email-response form-response"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Now, my problem is that Form 1 is working, Form 2 is not triggering the AJAX and works as normal form. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Given your code it should work fine. Are you sure the `#change-email` selector is correct and that there is only 1 element with that `id` in the page?

Comment: Post your markup. Either the ID doesn't exist, or there are non-unique ID's in the page.

Comment: please check if you are using id's
change-email or change-password twice in a page...

Comment: Posted the HTML part. Double checked and the #change-email is not used elsewhere in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `#change-email` has other binded events.

In **Firebug**, inspect `#change-email` element and go to `Event` tab.
In **Chrome**, inspect that element and go to `Event Listeners` tab.

You will see all binded events and corresponded callback functions.

If it will not help, try to submit a form manually from `Console`

1. Inspect a form, then run
2. `$($0).submit()`;

If it will work, looks like you have some events on you button.